# How update data exactly every seconds? AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want update my widget every seconds. So I use Service and Alarm Manager, but it doesn't update exactly every second.

This my log list:

```
  09-15 11:16:08.876: INFO/REPEAT(2850): time=11:16:08am
  09-15 11:16:09.970: INFO/REPEAT(2850): time=11:16:09am
  **09-15 11:16:11.025: INFO/REPEAT(2850): time=11:16:11am
  09-15 11:16:11.978: INFO/REPEAT(2850): time=11:16:11am**
  09-15 11:16:13.118: INFO/REPEAT(2850): time=11:16:12am
  09-15 11:16:14.048: INFO/REPEAT(2850): time=11:16:13am
  09-15 11:16:15.900: INFO/REPEAT(2850): time=11:16:15am
  09-15 11:16:16.533: INFO/REPEAT(2850): time=11:16:16am
  09-15 11:16:17.595: INFO/REPEAT(2850): time=11:16:17am
  09-15 11:16:17.845: INFO/REPEAT(2850): time=11:16:17am
  09-15 11:16:18.892: INFO/REPEAT(2850): time=11:16:18am
  09-15 11:16:20.212: INFO/REPEAT(2850): time=11:16:19am
  09-15 11:16:21.025: INFO/REPEAT(2850): time=11:16:20am
  09-15 11:16:21.861: INFO/REPEAT(2850): time=11:16:21am
```

This is my code:

```
public static final int INTERVAL = 1000; // 1 sec
public static final int FIRST_RUN = 0; // 0 seconds

  private void startService() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RepeatingAlarmService.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, REQUEST_CODE, intent, 0);

    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(
            AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + FIRST_RUN,
            INTERVAL,
            pendingIntent);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.v(this.getClass().getName(), "AlarmManger started at " + new java.sql.Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString());
}
```

RepeatingAlarmService.class:

```
 public class RepeatingAlarmService extends BroadcastReceiver {
public static final String CUSTOM_INTENT = "time to write";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.i("REPEAT","time="+getTimeString());
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(CUSTOM_INTENT);
    context.sendBroadcast(i);


}



public static String getTimeString() {
    String result = null;
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    if(cal.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM)
        result = new String(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02dam", cal.get(Calendar.HOUR), cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE),cal.get(Calendar.SECOND)));
    else
        result = new String(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02dpm", cal.get(Calendar.HOUR), cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE),cal.get(Calendar.SECOND)));
    return result;
}
```

}

How can I solve this problem? I need update all exactly every seconds

Answer (score 2):

From android manual:

> Note: The Alarm Manager is intended
>   for cases where you want to have your
>   application code run at a specific
>   time, even if your application is not
>   currently running. For normal timing
>   operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it
>   is easier and much more efficient to
>   use Handler.

You can use AlarmManager rather for getting data from server, etc. Only for actions which should be done every 5/15 minutes.

For animations use Handler.

I have also advice for you. Don't build animation based on fixed intervals. They will work smoothly only on RTOS machine >:] You should calculate timespan between previous and current updates. Use the timespan do simulate next frame.

Comment: Thanks for your response? but it doent work correctly Thereis my code:

Comment: final Handler mHandler=new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
  Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable() {
   
   public void run() {
    Log.i("TEST","FIRST_TIME"+FIRST_TIME_RUNNING+"when="+when+"time="+getTimeString());
    curTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
    writer.writeNext(strmas);
    if(!FIRST_TIME_RUNNING){
     when=curTime-prevTime;
    }
    FIRST_TIME_RUNNING=false;
    prevTime=curTime;
    mHandler.postDelayed(this, when);
   }
  });
  t.start();